# Getting invalid context errors

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, core-graphics

I don't have much code thus far, only this to start:

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(bounds.size, NO, 0);

    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
CGMutablePathRef outerPath;

CGMutablePathRef highlightPath;

CGRect outerRect = rectForRectWithInset(bounds, 1); 

CGRect highlightRect = CGRectMake(outerRect.origin.x,
                                      outerRect.origin.y + 1,
                                      outerRect.size.width,
                                      outerRect.size.height);
```

And then the problematic bit, which when commented out, the error goes away:

```
CGContextSaveGState(context);

CGContextAddPath(context, highlightPath);
CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(context, [[UIColor colorWithWhite:1.0 alpha:0.05]CGColor]);
CGContextFillPath(context);

CGContextRestoreGState(context);
```

Below that is simply:

```
UIImage *image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();

    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

Comment: how did you begin the image context?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it seems that either the bounds 0,0,0,0 or there is a problem with the highlightPath.  Where do these values come from?